# Excel Mac 2011 VBA, ByRef argument type mismatch with Worksheet argument

Tags: excel, vba

I'm tearing my hair out trying to get VBA to be happy.  I have a function which returns the name that the current sheet should have, depending on its contents.  Declared like this:

```
Function NewSheetName(OnSheet As Worksheet) As String
  Dim n As String
  n = Left(OnSheet.Name, 4)
  <set n based on sheet's contents>
  NewSheetName = n
End Function
```

To test it works, I have the following:

```
Sub try()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim s As String ' try to make VBA happy...doesnt make any difference
    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    If TypeOf ws Is Worksheet Then
        Debug.Print "Yup"
        s = NewSheetName(ws)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Nope"
    End If
End Sub
```

The Immediate window gets "Yup" but then VBA barfs, telling me there is a ByRef argument type mismatch.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about trying ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet instead of application.activesheet. The code is working for me, I feel that ws is not being set correctly.

Comment: Have just tried (didn't know about ThisWorkbook) -- same problem :-(   Just to be clear, this is Excel 2011 on a Mac.

Comment: you can try removing the constraint on the function - Function NewSheetName(OnSheet) As String, but probably no joy.

Comment: Oh. My. God.  It wasn't that line which had the problem.  It was actually a call inside NewSheetName, which was passing an undeclared argument to another function.  Gee, and I thought it was the line highlighted in yellow which was the problem.  Silly me.  Instead it was the thing highlighted as if I'd double-clicked on it.  Geez, M$.......   Thanks Lowpar, you pointed me in the direction of the solution!